# How to make a regex expression that will extract all cell numbers from a comma separated list of cells and subtract a constant value from each one?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, re2

I have a cell with a list of cells that fulfil a certain condition. `D3,D4,D5,D6` as an example. I have to use google sheet formulas to extract just the numbers and commas from the cell, while also subtracting 2 from each number.

I figured REGEXEXTRACT would be the only formula that would allow me to get what I want - I was however snagged, because REGEXEXTRACT uses RE2 (unlike Google Apps Script, which uses regular Regex).

I managed to figure out that `REGEXEXTRACT(F2, "(d+,)")` will retrieve the first number and comma from the cell, and in regular regex I'd need just use the `g` flag to get the rest of them - I've been looking for that flag in the RE2 syntax, but I couldn't find it.

EDIT: [A link to a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cV4kxeLL5HE9xpoCweLO_zfYTX6PqWFc4KrMb1yik0Q/edit?usp=sharing)

Input: `D3,D4,D5,D6`

Output: `1,2,3,4`

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Not a link to a spread sheed but an example posted here directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In F10 I entered this formula

```
=join(","; ArrayFormula(regexextract(split(F4; ","); "\d+")-2))
```

See if that works for you?